# discord:py highest role among a list of specific roles

Tags: discord.py

How do I perform the highest role of a user among some roles?
For example I have this category of roles:

[image]

And I wish that when I go to see a user's information, the highest role among them comes out?

Comment: member.top_role https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.top_role

Comment: yes but that gives the highest role of the user no among specific roles that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse `Member.roles` and find the first match:

```
@bot.command()
async def my_highest_role(ctx):
    highest = discord.utils.find(lambda role: role in my_roles, reversed(ctx.author.roles))
    if highest:
        await ctx.send(highest.name)
    else:
        await ctx.send("No such role")
```